# Overriding Copy Constructor for CObList MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I'm working in MFC, and I have my own templated class (CDFAObList) that is derived from CObList and can accept members of my own class (CDFAObject) that is derived from CObject. I need to override the compiler-generated copy constructor for CDFAObList because it eventually works its way down to CObject, which has private copy and assignment functions and gives me this:

```
1>error C2248: 'CObject::CObject' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'
1>see declaration of 'CObject::CObject'
1>see declaration of 'CObject'
1>This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'CObList::CObList(const CObList &)'
```

It gives me the above errors even though I have the copy constructor overridden and the assignment operator overloaded in CDFAObject. But when I try to override the copy constructor for CDFAObList, I get the following compiler errors:

```
1>error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>see reference to class template instantiation 'CDFAObList<T>' being compiled
```

Here's my templated class:

```
#include "DFAObject.h"
#include "DFAManDoc.h"
#include "DFAManTreeView.h"

template<class T> class CDFAObList : public CObList
{
 public:
    CDFAObList(void) { }


    CDFAObList(CDocument* pDoc,CTreeCtrl* pTree, xml_document* pXmlDoc)
    {
        doc = pDoc;
        Tree = pTree;
        xmlDoc = pXmlDoc;
    }

    // problem copy constructor
    CDFAObList(const CDFAOblist<T>& toCopy)
    {
        doc = toCopy.doc;
        Tree = toCopy.tree;
        xmlDoc = toCopy.xmlDoc;

        for (int i = 0; i < toCopy->GetSize(); i++)
        {
            this->AddHead( (T*) toCopy->GetTail());
        }
    }

protected:
    CDocument* doc;
    CTreeCtrl* Tree;
    xml_document* xmlDoc;
};
```

I've never used class templates before, so I'm probably doing a bunch of things wrong. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
CDFAObList(const CDFAObList<T>& toCopy)
```

instead of

```
CDFAObList(const CDFAOblist<T>& toCopy)
```

Comment: Thank you! That almost fixed the problem for me, I just had to change the `->` operators on `toCopy` to `.` operators as well :)